# How to fetch the data from database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

My database structure:

**Person**

```
id | name  |
1  | John  |
2  | Doe   |
3  | Marc  |
```

**Tasks**

```
task_id |  task_name| person_id
  1     |  Get milk |  1
  2     |   Play cs |  1
  3     |  Walk dog |  2
  4     | Eat fruit |  3
```

**comments**

```
id     | comment  | task
 1     | Which one |  1
 2     | When?    |  2
```

I have tried this:

```
function get_shapes2() {  
    $this->db->select('person.name,person.id,')
    ->select('GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT comments.id  separator " -/r/- ") as "commentid" ')
    ->select('GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT comments.comment  separator " -/r/- ") as "comment" ')
    ->select('GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tasks.task_name  separator " -/r/- ") as "tname"')
    ->select('GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tasks.task_id separator " -/r/- " ) as "id2"');    
    $this->db->from('person');
    $this->db->join('tasks', 'tasks.person_id = person.id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('comments', 'comments.task = tasks.task_id', 'left ');        
    $this->db->group_by('id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $res = array();
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $posts[] = $row->name;
        $posts[] = (int) $row->id;
        $posts[] = array_map(function($tname, $tid){
             return array('tname'=>$name,'tid'=>$tid);
        },
        explode(" -/r/- ",$row->tname),
        explode(" -/r/- ",$row->id2));
        array_push($res, $posts);
        unset($posts);
    }
    return $res;
}
```

What I get is:

```
{name: John,  id: 1, task =[ {tname: "Get milk", tid: "1"},{tname: "Play cs", tid: "2"}]}
```

What I am trying to do is for each person get all tasks and only 1 latest `comment, comment_id` if **comment exists** and store it in same array as the task

```
{name: John,  id: 1, task =[ {tname: "Get milk", tid: "1" comment: " Which one", commentid: 1 },{tname: "Play cs", tid: "2" comment: " When?", commentid: 2 }]}
```

The problem I have faced that I don't have any clue on how to do that.
I have tried adding it to `array_map` but it stores comments randomly it did not seem to work.

Comment: for each task you can have more comments isn't it ? If thats so your desirecd result doesn't make any sense...

Comment: I only need latest comment on every task if comment exists there can be more comments thou tasks may repet

Comment: @StefanAvramovic Instead of doing a `left join` on `comments` table, you can do a `left join` on this nested query: `select * from comments where id in (select max(id) from comments group by task);`. This nested query only shows the latest comments.

Answer (score 0):

please use jquery to catch json data--it is easy way to catch

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$.getJSON("YOUR_PHP_LINK",function(data)
        {
            var tb = $("#tab");
            $.each(data,function(i,value)
            {
                tb.append("<tr><td>Name: " + value.name + "</td><td>ID: " + value.id+ "    </td></tr>");
            });
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Refer the below query    


$this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('comments');
    $this->db->join('Tasks', 'comments.task=Tasks.task_id ', 'left');
    $this->db->join('Person', 'Tasks.person_id=Person.id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('comments.task', 1); //Provide id here...
    $this->db->order_by("comments.id", "desc");
    return $this->db->get()->result();
```